# Mac OS X - kinit not using /etc/krb5.conf

Tags: macos, authentication, kerberos

I have a /etc/krb5.conf file which specifies the default realm as EXAMPLE.COM however when performing a kinit this is not picked up.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issue was a include line in my /etc/krb5.conf file which was not valid.